# git push and server permissions

Tags: git, unix

I've a LAMP environment on my VPS where I would like to set up a versioning system.  I'm using git and right now I did in order these things:

- I created a git user and its relative home in `/home/git`
- I created `/var/git` folder where I'm storing all `--bare` repositories
- I created my working directory in `/var/www/myproject` initialized with `git init` and linked with `git remote add hub` to my bare directory
- I created inside `/var/git/myproject.git/hooks` a post-update that pulls files into my working directory in `/var/wwww/myproject`

Now my problem is that my `/var/www` and all subdirectories are assigned to the `www-data` user and group and with these everything works like a charm but after a pull or an init from git things have as user and group `git:git` and permission of course breaks in ftp, web installers etc.

Any one have an idea on how to proceed at this point? many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the git user to the www-data group: `sudo usermod -a -G www-data git` should help - more info at http://machiine.com/2013/easy-way-to-give-user-permission-to-edit-and-add-files-in-varwww/

Comment: i would like to use post-update to rewrite permissions but i don't know a good way to do it :S

Comment: Set up a cron task to change ownership of /var/www every half hour or so?